# fill vue-search-select with axios and laravel api

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-9, vue-select

I´m trying to fill my component vue-search-select with axios get and my laravel API. I´m receiving my data ok, but i can´t fill my select. In console i can show this:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

But in my component i have all my data:

```
Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an     issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/core
```

at <ModelListSelect options= (602) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},   {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},  {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},  {…}, {…}, …] option-value="code" option-text="name"  ... >

i don´t understand very well that i´m doing wrong.

**i´m working with vue js 3 and composition API.**

my code it´s:

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    import { ModelSelect } from 'vue-search-select'
    import { ModelListSelect } from 'vue-search-select'
    import "vue-search-select/dist/VueSearchSelect.css"
    const getAllItems = ref([])

    const item = {
       code: '',
       name: ''
    }

    const allItems = () => {
       axios.get('/api/getAllItems').then((response) => {
         getAllItems.value = response.data.data;
      });
    }
   allItems();
```

and my component call it:

```
<model-list-select :options="getAllItems"
   option-value="code"
   option-text="name"
   v-model="item"
   placeholder="Seleccionar más articulos">
</model-list-select>
```

I´m trying to fill my select with seeker i can show all my data in my console.log() but i have error that i don´t understand

Comment: My problem was with v-model and option-value. I resolve my problem